# Jmeter load test - What will be internet speed for each thread when running the test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, bandwidth

If speedtest shows me internet speed of my machine as 50 Mbps and if I run jmeter load test with 50 users from that machine.

Does that mean each thread is having 1 Mbps internet speed ?

I need to give below statement to my client,
"Application response time is X when 50 users with Y internet speed are using it"

Comment: You'll need to know the payload of your request. If the request is an index page of the site and all markup/assets/etc/ total to 1MB (8 Mb), on a 80 Mbps line, you can serve 10 requests simultaneously before your bandwidth is choked - assuming each user can download at 8 Mbps. If your payload is 8 times less, that'd be (125 KB) 1 Megabit. On 80 Mbps line, 80 users can simultaneously consume the webpage even when their download is 1 Mbps. So, first find your payload. Assume the worst; assume nobody is caching.

Comment: Take best case scenario of caching. If repeat requests generate 100Kbps, you can serve 800 concurrent users. Then, check the bottleneck of your server. Can your webserver handle that many connections simultaneously? Can your database handle that workload? How many queries per request get executed? 10 queries? If webserver supports 100 concurrent users, can your DB execute 1000 requests per second? Give generic idea to your client. Test the system under load and give them that result.